# Completely new to vectors. Vector subscript out of range

Tags: c++, vector

For my assignment, I am supposed to take a group of names and numbers and put them into vectors and use them for a phonebook. It's worth mentioning I am converting the code from an original version that used arrays per the assignment. Now, unfortunately, the lectures provided by my professor only covered some of the absolute basics and didn't show hardly anything for any of the specifics so I have been left to dig for most everything. I know the error likely has something to do with the size of the vector but I have no clue what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it.

```
int main()
{
    //variables
    string eleName;
    int elePhone;
    char choice;
    vector<string> name;
    name.push_back(string(10, 10));
    name = { "Andrico", "Bonnie", "Charles",
                        "Debbie", "Enrique", "Felicia" };
    vector<int> phone;
    phone.push_back(10);
    phone = { 5551234,
                        5555678,
                        5552468,
                        5551379,
                        5559876,
                        5554321 };



    do
    {
        //call function showPhoneBook
        showPhoneBook(name, phone, MAX);

        //get user request
        cout << "\n\nWho\'s phone number do you want to see?" << endl;
        cout << "remember, type \'e\' for edit and \'x\' for exit, otherwise just type the number of the person." << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        //call function toChoice
        elePhone = toChoice(choice);
        if (elePhone != -1)
        {
            cout << "The phone number for " << name[elePhone] << " is " << phone[elePhone] << ".\n\n\n\n\n\n";
        }
        if (choice == 'e')
        {
            int choice1;
            cout << "Which entry do you want to edit?  ";
            cin >> choice1;
            editNum(name, phone, MAX, choice1);
        }
    } while (choice != 'x');

    return 0;
}

void showPhoneBook(vector<string> N, vector<int> P, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << i << "  " << N[i] << "\t" << P[i] << endl;
        cout << "Size of the phone book " << N.size() << endl;

    }
    return;
}

int toChoice(char c)
{
    int num=0;
    if (c != 'e' && c != 'x')
    {
        switch (c)
        {
        case '0':
            num = 0;
            return num;
        case '1':
            num = 1;
            return num;
        case '2':
            num = 2;
            return num;
        case '3':
            num = 3;
            return num;
        case '4':
            num = 4;
            return num;
        case '5':
            num = 5;
            return num;
        case '6':
            num = 6;
            return num;
        case '7':
            num = 7;
            return num;
        case '8':
            num = 8;
            return num;
        case '9':
            num = 9;
            return num;

        }

    }
    else
        return -1;
    return num;
}

void editNum(vector<string> N, vector<int> P, int size, int c1)
{
    string name;
    int number;
    cout << "What is the name for entry " << c1 << "?:  ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "What is the number for entry " << c1 << "?:  ";
    cin >> number;

    N[c1] = name;
    P[c1] = number;
    return;
}
```

Comment: You don't have a book?

Comment: Remove the lines where you do: name.push_back(string(10, 10)); and phone.push_back(10)

Comment: Where does the error occur?  [Edit] the question to include the `toChoice` and `showPhoneBook` functions.

Comment: Just a side note , make sure you are using the right standard while compiling. Something like  `-std=c++17`

Comment: Try to make a more minimal [mre]. If you make it really small, then the error will probably reveal itself to you.

Comment: What is the value of `MAX`? Maybe replace it with `std::min(name.size(), phone.size())`

Answer (score -1):

```
vector<int> phone;
    phone.push_back(10);
    phone = { 5551234,
                        5555678,
                        5552468,
                        5551379,
                        5559876,
                        5554321 };
```

phone.push_back(10) actually act like phone[0] = 10;
I think you intended
"phone.resize(10);  "
which means 'phone' has 10 size.

Comment: That's a pretty reasonable guess about the OP's intent. But it's worth noting that even if they use `resize()`, the size will be set to 6 by the following assignment.